# Google script, how to access and paste on edit to a specific sheet within another spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, synchronization

I am attempting to create a script so that when a change is made in one spreadsheet the corresponding sheet with the same name in another spreadsheet receives the same change in the same place, and so I can put one lot of the script in each one and get two linked sheets that affect each other.

this is the code:

```
var targetID = 'ID of the sheet';
var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();

function onEdit(e){
  var range = e.range;
  var value = e.value;
  var row = range.getRowIndex();
  var column = range.getColumnIndex();
  exportValue(row,column,value)
} 

function exportValue(row,column,value) {
  //(**this is the point where it breaks**)
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetID).getSheetByName(targetSheet);
  var target = s.getRange(row, column);
  target.setValue(value);
}
```

In my version i put in logs in between each line to see where it failed and it got to the line where i have put "*this is the point where it breaks*" and then didn't return anything after that.

Since attempting this I tried to open up the other file by just pulling out all of the variables but I couldn't get it to work.

the current error messages that it is going with are:

> Cannot find function getSheetByName in object Sheet
>
> Cannot find function openById in object Spreadsheet

I have spent so much time on this already and I feel like the answer is really simple but I would really appreciate any advice

Thanks in advance

:)

Comment: Did you put the target Id here? `var targetID = 'ID of the sheet';`

Comment: @Cooper thanks for your comment, I put that in just so that people couldn't see my link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Linked Spreadsheets with Installable onEdit() triggers

I got this to work by using an installable onEdit(e) Trigger.

```
function Linked1Edit(e){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('The Other Spreadsheets ID');
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(e.range.getSheet().getName());
  var rg=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart);
  rg.setValue(e.value);
}
```

I called one Linked1Edit(e) and the other Linked2Edit(e) and created an installable onEdit(e) trigger for each one and now they write to each other.
Unfortunately, it only works for single valued changes though.

The following script will allow you to make changes to more than one value at a time.

```
function Linked1Edit(e){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('The Other Spreadsheet ID');
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(e.range.getSheet().getName());
  var rg=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart,e.range.rowEnd-e.range.rowStart+1,e.range.columnEnd-e.range.columnStart+1);
  var vA=e.range.getValues();
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```

- [Event Object Link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Creating a Trigger

Select Current Project's Triggers

[image]

Click Add Trigger:

[image]

Create Trigger Dialog:

[image]

You can also create a trigger in code.  See [ScriptApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I cant see why it wouldn't work but it doesn't. I put loggers in but it doesn't seem to get past the ss line, can you think of a reason for this

Comment: I have just tried taking the exact same function and removing all of the 'e.' stuff so that it just goes to a specific cell and writes 'it worked!!!' and it did work, so i tried to put it back into onEdit format and it didn't work, I really dont know what to do

Comment: I gather you’re trying to run the function from the script editor and that’s a mistake.

Comment: Also it won’t work with a simple trigger so you can’t just name it onEdit(e) and have it run you need to use an installable onEdit trigger and point it to the name of the function. A trigger that you build in project triggers dialog. Opening another spreadsheet requires permissions simple triggers don’t handle processes that require permissions.

Comment: By the way I tested this code. it was fun to play with

Comment: See images above to create installable onEdit() trigger.  You can also do it in code.

Comment: thank you so much, this has honestly been suck a pain to get working, the only issue and its a really small one is that when I delete the information in a box on the other end it says 'undefined', is there a way to fix this without another onEdit or not? I tried using an if statement saying that if  e.range= 'undefined' then let it equal ' '  but it didn't work?